# Bug in C# System.Collections.Generic.List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a simple code to read some data from a text file and storing in a C# List but having problems with it. Please help if the problem is at my side or is it the library. I've written the following function :

```
public List<EmpBO> ReadData()
        {
            EmpBO temp = new EmpBO();
            List<EmpBO> lis = new List<EmpBO>(100);
            string[] tokens;
            string data;
            StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(new FileStream("emp.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            int ind = 0;
            while ((data = sw.ReadLine())!=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading " + data);
                tokens = data.Split(';');
                temp.Id = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
                temp.Name = tokens[1];
                temp.Salary = double.Parse(tokens[2]);
                temp.Br = double.Parse(tokens[3]);
                temp.Tax = double.Parse(tokens[4]);
                temp.Designation = tokens[5];
                //lis.Add(temp);
                lis.Insert(ind,temp);
                ind++;

            }
            sw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Read this material and returning list");
            for (int i = 0; i < lis.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("" + (lis.ElementAt(i)).Name);
            }
                //foreach (EmpBO ob in lis)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("" + ob.Id + ob.Name);
                //}
                return lis;
        }
```

File emp.txt Contains:

> 1;Ahmed;100000;20;1000;manager
>  
>   2;Bilal;200000;15;2000;ceo

Now as you can see that in while loop, I've displayed what StreamReader has read and it does 2 iterations in this case and displays.

> Reading 1;Ahmed;100000;20;1000;manager
>   Reading 2;Bilal;200000;15;2000;ceo

and as you can see i'm saving this info in temp and inserting in the list. 
after the while loop is finished , when I traverse the list for knowing that what is stored in it then it displays:

> Read this material and returning list
>  
>   Bilal
>  
>   BIlal

Well, the second record is stored in the list twice and 1st record is absent.. What seems to be the problem? I've used Add() method too , and foreach loop for traversing list as you can see it's commented out but the result was same.. Please help

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2012 ultimate

Comment: As a general rule, any problem you're experiencing is not due to a bug in the compiler or runtime library.

Comment: Please type "select isn't broken" into your favourite search engine.  Software contains bugs; what is more likely: that your software that you wrote contains a bug, or that the most heavily used collection class in .NET contains a bug? Also please read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move this line

```
EmpBO temp = new EmpBO();
```

into the while-loop so that it looks like

```
while ((data = sw.ReadLine())!=null){
  EmpBO temp = new EmpBO();
  Console.WriteLine("Reading " + data);
  tokens = data.Split(';');
  temp.Id = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
  temp.Name = tokens[1];
  temp.Salary = double.Parse(tokens[2]);
  temp.Br = double.Parse(tokens[3]);
  temp.Tax = double.Parse(tokens[4]);
  temp.Designation = tokens[5];
  //lis.Add(temp);
  lis.Insert(ind,temp);
  ind++;

}
```

You are not creating a new `EmpBO` for each entry, but more overwriting the same object with the read values and adding it again to the List.

The effect is that you add the same object mutiple times to the List.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it would be nice to explain why it is the correct answer.

Comment: BUt as you can see, it has inserted 2nd record twice but it should have inserted 1st record twice... isn't it?

Comment: @Jehof kindly explain

Comment: @Ahmed No, you add the same object 2 times to the List and with the last loop the object has the values of the 2nd record.

Comment: @Jehof can you please elaborate it? in first iteration temp has value of 1st record and it's written cuz i'm adding to list in loop, so in second iteration, temp is over written by second record and now it's insertd again, so 2nd record should be inserted isn't it? and we should have 1st n 2nd record in the list?

Comment: @Ahmed I think you should take a look at reference and value types in .NET

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have created the EmpBO  object only once. In the second iteration you are modified the value in the same object. you have to create instance for EmpBO inside the while loop like below.

```
while ((data = sw.ReadLine())!=null)
{
Console.WriteLine("Reading " + data);
tokens = data.Split(';');
EmpBO temp = new EmpBO();
temp.Id = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
temp.Name = tokens[1];
temp.Salary = double.Parse(tokens[2]);
temp.Br = double.Parse(tokens[3]);
temp.Tax = double.Parse(tokens[4]);
temp.Designation = tokens[5];
//lis.Add(temp);
lis.Insert(ind,temp);
ind++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but your code has other problems.

Both your `FileStream` and `StreamReader` should be disposed of after use.

Alternatively, you could write your code like this:

```
public List<EmpBO> ReadData()
{
    return File
        .ReadAllLines("emp.txt")
        .Select(data =>
        {
            var tokens = data.Split(';');
            return new EmpBO()
            {
                Id = int.Parse(tokens[0]),
                Name = tokens[1],
                Salary = double.Parse(tokens[2]),
                Br = double.Parse(tokens[3]),
                Tax = double.Parse(tokens[4]),
                Designation = tokens[5],
            };
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

That, hopefully, should be even easier.

Comment: With all due respect, this doesn't answer the question, and still leaves lots of room for errors (null checks, parse errors, a better `.Select(...)` statement. Yes, your code is better and clearer, but it doesn't help the OP solve his problem in any way.

Comment: @Maarten - I appreciate your comment. I did say at the beginning of my answer that it "isn't a direct answer to the question". My intent was to offer a cleaner alternative that would get the OP past his current issue and hopefully help him move forward. It seemed to me that a direct answer to his question would still leave his code quite fragile so I thought this answer would be worth his while.

Answer (score 0):

You've inserted the same object twice. You have to create a new object in the loop otherwise you will override the attributes on each iteration and simply and a reference to the same object over and over again.It's safe to assume that standard operations on the BCL classes work correctly or as Eric Lippert put's it [Maybe there's something wrong with the universe but probably not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx?Redirected=true)

you simply need to change the start of the loop to this:

```
while ((data = sw.ReadLine())!=null)
{
    EmpBO temp = new EmpBO();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add same object twice in a list ,it will override values entered first time and will show only values from second object but twice 
for example :Take a list ,add a object in it . modify that object ,again add it .
when you try to print values ,you will get values of last object

```
ob1.a=5;
list1.add(ob1);
```

// list1[0]-->a-->5

```
ob1.a=7;
list1.add(ob1);
```

//  list1[0]--->a--->7  list1[1]--->a--->7